# Can お[邪魔]{じゃま}します be used in cases of long-term stay?

Tags: usage, set-phrases

So I need to write an email for an assignment where I am an exchange student who is going to Japan and staying at someone's house for a period of time.

I want to begin with "thank you very much for having me" which would normally be お邪魔します as watching Japanese shows with subtitles have taught me. But I feel like お邪魔します feels more like a short-time thing like "sorry for the (temporary) intrusion" as opposed to something along the lines of what I want to say.

What would be more correct in the context that I am writing in?

Comment: お邪魔します would be appropriate for the moment of entering into the host family's house, regardless it's a short stay or a long term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think お邪魔します is used in cases of short-term stay as you said.

I think お世話になります is natural in cases of long-term stay.

Comment: Would it be correct to say お世話になることを感謝しています?

Comment: It's effusive.　お世話になります。よろしくお願いします。 is better.

Comment: In my desperate attempt to use some grammar structures... would お世話になるので、感謝しています be okay or is it also iffy?

Comment: お世話になる include already showing your appreciation, so I hear rarely お世話になるので、感謝しています but if you use them, your appreciation will get through them.

Comment: @Spica 感謝しています almost sounds like someone saved you from a fire or bankruptcy.  Perhaps it is more common in business scenes where exaggeration is ubiquitous.